# Android - Host a server inside local network?

Tags: android, server, localhost, wifi, chat

I would like to create an `application` which can interact between `devices` in a same network. Like D`oodle army 2: Mini Militia`., one device will act as Hosting machine and all other devices(in the same network) will connect and chat among the group. Any suggestion and guidance are welcome. Sharing any tutorial for sample `application` is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are some references:

- [Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer)
- [P2P Connections](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)

Cheers!